# Initializer is misinterpreting the argument's data type

Tags: ios, swift

I am decoding data as shown on the right window and then using it to output a model via the initializer defined in the middle one. However, when I try to use it, I am being told that I am passing the wrong argument type.

Why is it that I am getting an error that the initializer is expecting a String, if I have defined it in the Model (the middle screen) to explicitly expect a [String] ?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8LQ1.png)

Comment: Please post code as _text_, not a screenshot. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: Look closely at your initialiser declaration. Genre comes after background image. This is why you always add argument labels... I assume this is a typo?

Comment: Thank you @Sweeper, you are correct - the arguments inside the initializer were in the wrong order.

Comment: you're passing genre which is of type [String] to backgroundImage parameter which is of type String. Change in order will solve the issue. You should have argument labels for readability at call site n to avoid such mistakes in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two of the arguments - `genre` and `backgroundImage` - are swapped, which causes the issue with the Initializer.